# Can not get NAT working on Cisco 2851 Router

Tags: networking, nat, cisco-ios

I am trying to get a 2851 router setup using static routing and NAT. My college uses static routing, otherwise I wouldn't ;-)
I can ping addresses on the internet from the router console, but not from a machine on the inside network. I can ping the inside router port from a network client but not the outside port. I think I have all of the NAT stuff in there correctly, but still no routing. Can anyone else point out my mistake?

```
CSLabRouter#sho run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 3621 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname CSLabRouter
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 51200 warnings
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
ip cef
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
voice-card 0
 no dspfarm
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-3695308060
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-3695308060
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-3695308060
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-3695308060
 certificate self-signed 01
  3082023E 308201A7 A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050030 
  31312F30 2D060355 04031326 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274 
  69666963 6174652D 33363935 33303830 3630301E 170D3136 30393033 30333032 

  BC404C81 47004B31 4B3E456C 81E50FC7 E3C9F387 BBB7B8CD 98CC230C 4068B586 FC92
  quit
username Admin privilege 15 password 0 MasterPass
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.30.30.1 255.255.0.0
 ip nat enable
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.13.13.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat enable
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip default-gateway 172.30.30.1
ip default-network 172.30.0.0
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.30.30.2
ip route 10.13.13.0 255.255.255.0 172.30.30.2
!
!
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip nat pool AC008Clients 10.13.13.0 10.13.13.255 prefix-length 24 add-route
ip nat source list 1 pool AC008Clients overload
ip nat source static udp 10.13.13.8 53 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 53
ip nat source static tcp 10.13.13.8 53 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 53
ip nat source static udp 10.13.13.8 5900 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 5900
ip nat source static tcp 10.13.13.8 5900 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 5900
ip nat source static udp 10.13.13.8 3283 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 3283
ip nat source static tcp 10.13.13.8 3283 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 3283
ip nat source static udp 10.13.13.8 311 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 311
ip nat source static tcp 10.13.13.8 311 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 311
ip nat source static tcp 10.13.13.8 80 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 80
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
!
access-list 1 permit 10.13.13.0 0.0.0.255
snmp-server community CottonCandy RO
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
alias exec s show ip int br
alias exec sr show run
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 privilege level 15
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using "ip nat enable" commend under the interfaces, and "ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload" in global config.

When we use the "ip nat enable command", we also need to slightly modify the nat statement in global config as well (to remove the word "inside" in global config).

Otherwise use "ip nat inside/outside" command.